# Storing data files on Django application

Tags: python, django, database, data-visualization, data-mining

I am building a web application that allows users to login and upload data files that would eventually be used to perform data visualisation and data mining features - Imagine a SAS EG/Orange equivalent on the web.

What are the best practices to store these files (in a database or on file) to facilitate efficient retrieval and processing of the data and the pros and cons of each method?

Comment: Generally, it's not recommended to store files in the database. Consider using a media server for user-generated files and their uploads. Then you may process them with python as you would normally do.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what functionality you can offer.

Many very interesting data mining tools will read raw data files only, so storing the data in a database does not help you anything.

But then you won't want to run them "on the web" anyway, as they easily eat all your resources.

Either way, first get your requirements straight and explicit, then settle on the analysis tools, then decide on the storage backend depending on what the tools can use.